# one table contains two column a and b if col a = col b then it will print first value otherwise it will print both values

Tags: mysql

one table contains two column a and b
if col a = col b then it will print first value otherwise it will print both values.

```
     a    b
------------------------------------------

    100  100        
    101  102
    103  105    
    102  102
```

required out put

```
    100
    101  102
    103  105
    102
```

Comment: Use case .. when

Answer (score 2):

```
select a, 
       case when a = b  
            then null 
            else b 
       end as b
from your_table
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this query

```
SELECT a, IF(a=b,'',b) FROM your_table_name
```